# Como eu faço para uma imagem ultrapassar os limites de uma DIV

Tags: css, posicionamento

Estou com dificuldade de colocar uma imagem 100% na tela mobile, que tem uma margem na DIV anterior, já tentei mudar o position, overflow e float mas não consigo passar desta margem.
segue um exemplo

```css
.teste{
 margin: 20px auto;
 width: 1000px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 text-align: center;
}
.teste1{
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 width: 1200px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>teste</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="teste">
  <div class="teste1">
   
  </div>
  <div class="teste2">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

no caso seria ultrapassar a div em vermelho sobre a margem usada na div azul.

Comment: Onde estaria a imagem?

Answer (score 1):

Giancarlo, tudo bem?

Existem algumas formas que você possa implementar isso. Uma das mais fáceis que eu acredito resolver seu problema é utilizar duas propriedades do css: margin e z-index;
Com o margin você pode colocar sua div iniciando em cima da outra e o z-index define qual está à frente e qual está atras.

```
.teste1 {
 z-index: 2;
 background: red;
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0.8; /* Define uma opacidade para o elemento sobreposto*/
}

.teste2 {
 z-index: 1;
 background: blue;
 margin-top: -10px;
 position: relative;
}
```

Desta forma é possível vc definir o ínicio da div dentro da div vermelha, mas fazer com que ela esteja atrás.
Contudo, o efeito será parecido ao que já se têm. Para dar um efeito de sobreposição ou transição, você pode usar a opacidade da div, fazendo uma transição entre o azul e o vermelho.

Answer (score 0):

Para esse caso, utilize no seu CSS:

```
.teste1{
    /* Display inline block trava a imagem na tela */
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria de uma maneira diferente, criaria uma div chamada .container e para esta colocaria uma margem de 20px auto. Deste modo você pode estender a imagem por toda a largura e quando o quiser que o elemento fique com a margem de 20px você o encapsula com a div .container. Exemplo

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="imagem">
      <img src="nome.png" />
   </div>
   <div id="texto">
      <div class="container">
         Texto
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<style>
   #main{width:100%;}
   #imagem img {width:100%}
   .container{margin: 20px auto;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer algo do tipo em css:

```css
.teste{
  margin: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 600px){
  .teste{
    margin: 0px;
    /*Aqui é onde vc vai tirar a margem do campo que precisa*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="teste"></div>
```